# How to set JsonSerializer default settings globally

Tags: jsonserializer, asp.net-core-3.0

For `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`, I have to set the options every time I serialize or deserialize or have to set attributes on every property of the object, due to lack of a way to set/change the default settings. At least I am not able to find one.

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TypeListDTO>(
    "{\"listNo\":33}", 
    new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase});
```

Is there such a way available? If not, is there a workaround available?

**EDIT: I am using .Net Core 3 with Endpoint Routing. But could very well not be using it at all.**

Answer (score 0):

Try it with AddJsonOptions(Action) in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc()
  .AddJsonOptions( options =>
  {
    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
  });
```

Comment: That is an MVC provided function, isnt it? What if I am not using MVC? Is there any other way of using this?

Comment: @Abhi yes it is a MVC function, but you're not forced to make MVC you can use it in plain WebAPI projects